Spring Cloud Stream | StreamBridge | Handle Failure
I am using Spring Cloud Stream version 4.1 to produce message to Kafka. Below is my code where I am using streamBridge to do so.
streamBridge.send("myTopic", "payload");

Now I want to handle failure scenario where Kafka is down. I am expecting above code to throw exception if Kafka is down. But that is not happening and it always returns true.
I have tried using below configuration but it's not working
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:54442
          producer-properties:
            ack: all # with just this, thread gets stuck for infinite time if kafka is down
            delivery.timeout.ms: 10000 # with this streamBridge.send() always throw exception


If Kafka is down completely when you call send, what is the behavior you are observing? Does it return immediately with a true value? If so, that scenario should be easily reproducible. Could you check this on your end?

Yes, by default it immidiately returns true
